# Preimage of a maximal ideal is maximal in free ring extensions

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, group-rings

Suppose that $A, B$ are commutative rings with identity, and we
have an injective ring homomorphism $A \hookrightarrow B$.

I would like to know wether or not the following proposition is true:
**If $B$ is free as an $A$-module, then the preimage of any maximal ideal of $B$ is maximal in $A$.**

Motivation: I want to show that any maximal ideal of a group ring $R[G]$ ($G$ is an arbitrary group) over a local ring $R$ contains $1\cdot \mathfrak m_R$ where $\mathfrak m_R$ is the
unique maximal ideal of $R$.

Comment: The classic example is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x]$ (where $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the localization at the prime ideal $(p)$), and the preimage of the maximal ideal $(px-1)$ is $0$

Comment: I also don't know why you're asking about commutative rings, if your motivation is looking at group rings over arbitrary groups

Comment: @math54321 indeed, I should have not required the commutativity. I just hoped that the commutative case is more simple. Anyway, I guess the statement is false and can not be saved. I needed it for a proposition that I know is true, but I guess for some other reason. Thank you for the comments.